# Using OEM key from a preinstalled windows copy

Tags: windows-7, laptop, installation

I have a lenovo laptop running linux. I have the OEM key for win7 (looks like numbers-OEM-numbers-numbers) that came with the laptop. Can I reinstall Windows 7 from my USB drive and use the OEM key to get it to work? Lenovo sent me some recovery disks, but they only work if windows is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you install the same version of Windows 7 that the key is for, there should not be any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an OEM version to use an OEM key... I would suggest that you contact the OEM and tell them that you put a larger HD into your machine and you need to reinstall the OS... usually for $5 they will mail you an OEM install disk.